# summarisng sequences in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set to stastically analyse comprising 45,000 days of a rainwater system switching between running on a tank or off the city water mains.

The system switches between the two depending on the level in the tank. I am using a 129 year data set. the length of each on and off sequence ranges from 1 to up to 300 (days).

looks like this:

```
> dput(head(mydata))
structure(list(day = 1:6, on.mains = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), on.tank = 0:5, date2 = 18890101:18890106, year = c(1889, 1889, 
1889, 1889, 1889, 1889), On.which = c("on.tank", "on.tank", "on.tank", 
"on.tank", "on.tank", "on.tank"), id2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and also at the end:

```
> dput(tail(mydata))
structure(list(day = 47220:47225, on.mains = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), on.tank = 48:53, date2 = 20180414:20180419, year = c(2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), On.which = c("on.tank", "on.tank", 
"on.tank", "on.tank", "on.tank", "on.tank"), id2 = c(130L, 130L, 
130L, 130L, 130L, 130L)), row.names = 47220:47225, class = "data.frame")
>
```

Innorder to better understand the large data set and output, what I am trying to do is have a data frame that contains (summarises) for each year; the year, the lengths of each the sequences and the count of the number of  these sequences. e.g. say in 1889 would be 10 5-day sequences, 20 1-day sequences, 2 100-day sequences, etc.

I see that a kind of run length encoding would be whats required (and I can get this to work on an extracted single column) but as this only works on a single column I lose all the year and other data. Ideally if I could do rle on a column, grouped by year, and keep it as a data frame would probably work. But I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: Interesting coding problem, but I have a feeling it will be moved over to StackOverflow. Within a year, do you have sequences like 0,0,..., 0, then 1,1,...,1, then 0,0,..., 0, and so on, alternating between 0 and 1? Does 0 mean the tank is on and 1 mean the tank is off?

Comment: yes that is essentially the raw data, but it has been processed to be a series of sequences 1,2,3,4,5,6,7..41 etc which can be anywhere from 1 up to about 300 days long. Each sequence ends with a zero when the system flips over to the mains or tank. so the on.mains variable has zeros when the on.tank is counting up a sequence then vice versa when the tank runs out.